# How to get image full absolute path using richtext

Tags: richtext

This is my source code, Im using richtext for the link of the images. I've encountered a problem, the image is not loading because it needs to have a full path.

```
<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/images/submissions/12908/editor/03-22-2023_1159am.jpg" alt="" width="505" height="272">
```

it should be like this. This is my first time in this kind of problem.

```
    <p><img src="https://dummy.com/images/submissions/12159/editor/04-11-2023_0824am.jpg" alt="dumm" /></p></div>
```